# How to subscribe inside observable and return observable

Tags: angular, observable

I want to get result of an observable and make some changes and then return the result with type of observable again for components to subscribe. this is my code:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';



    get_items() {
this.http.get(this.router_url).map(res => res.json()).catch(this.handleRequestError).subscribe(
(result) => {
    result = result.data[0].my_item
    return Observable.of( data: [{my_items: result}]});
},
(error) => {}
)
}
```

the problem is in component that is using and trying to .subscribe result of get_items() they get error of : Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:

> this.generalService.get_items(...).subscribe is not a function

but when I return just:

```
return Observable.of( data: [{my_items: result}]});
```

it works fine but it's not what I want
any way, the result type is Observable so why I get this error?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
get_items() {
    this.http.get(this.router_url).map(res => {
        const result = res.json();
        return {data: [{my_items: result.data[0].my_item}]};
    });
}
```

The `map` operator is the place where you should modify your response before actually subscribe to it.

Answer (score 1):

As angular doc says `HttpClient`'s `get()`  returns a Observable. So you dont have to create a new one.

> ```
> /**
>  * Construct a GET request which interprets the body as JSON and returns it.
>  *
>  * @return an `Observable` of the body as type `T`.
>  */
> get<T>(url: string, options?: {
>     headers?: HttpHeaders | {
>         [header: string]: string | string[];
>     };
>     observe?: 'body';
>     params?: HttpParams | {
>         [param: string]: string | string[];
>     };
>     reportProgress?: boolean;
>     responseType?: 'json';
>     withCredentials?: boolean;
> }): Observable<T>;
> ```

Try this. And replace `any` with the interface that represents the response;

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

get_items() Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get<any>(this.router_url).map(res => res.json());
}
```

And in the component.

```
this.service.get_items().subscribe((res) => {
 // request data will be here in the res
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into something similar, and this is how I resolved it.

**FooService.ts**

```
private fetchFoo(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpService.get('/foo');
}

public async getFoo(): Promise<Foo[]> {
   if(this.foo.length === 0) {
       return this.fetchFoo()
           .toPromise() <-- use in place of .subscribe
           .then((response) => {
                this.foo = response.data;
                return this.foo;
            }, (err) => {
                console.debug(err);
                return this.foo;
           });
    } else {
       return this.foo;
    }
}
```

**AnyComponent.ts**

```
public getFoo(): void {
   this.fooService.getFoo().then((response) => {
        this.doSomething(response);
   })
}
```

Using `.toPromise` instead of `.subscribe` to handle the observable will still execute the network call, and sets the exposed service function to be a promise which is thenable, instead of a subscription which would need to be unsubscribed from.